# OData - get individual property of an entity

Tags: azure-active-directory, odata

I was using

https://graph.windows.net/aaa2a672-ae0e-4ac3-9aec-xxxxxx/groups?api-version=1.6&$filter=displayName%20eq%20'kevingroup2'

to get data of kevingroup2

The response was

{
    "odata.metadata": "https://graph.windows.net/aaa2a672-ae0e-4ac3-9aec-xxxx/$metadata#directoryObjects",
    "value": [
        {
            "odata.type": "Microsoft.DirectoryServices.Group",
            "objectType": "Group",
            "objectId": "b5685a42-1de7-478d-94b4-de50ac9a2222",
            "deletionTimestamp": null,
            "description": "kevin group 2",
            "dirSyncEnabled": null,
            "displayName": "kevingroup2",
            "lastDirSyncTime": null,
            "mail": null,
            "mailNickname": "d6460146-0",
            "mailEnabled": false,
            "onPremisesDomainName": null,
            "onPremisesNetBiosName": null,
            "onPremisesSamAccountName": null,
            "onPremisesSecurityIdentifier": null,
            "provisioningErrors": [],
            "proxyAddresses": [],
            "securityEnabled": true
        }
    ]
}

How do I extract objectId of the record?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just need to use the api with the filter as below:

```
https://graph.windows.net/xxxxxxxxx/groups?$filter=displayName eq 'kevingroup2'&$select=objectId
```

By the way, Microsoft recommends customers to use microsoft graph rather than azure ad graph. So you can refer to [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/group-list?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http) microsoft graph api to get the groups.

Comment: Thanks Hury, up to now, Microsoft Graph does not support Azure AD.  If I want to get the value of objectId, what do I need to do?

Comment: Hi @KevinPham I'm not so clear about your concern, do you mean you want to get the value of objectId in your c# code(after get the result from the api) ?

Comment: Hi @Hury I am getting      {
    "odata.metadata": "https://graph.windows.net/aaa2a672-ae0e-4ac3-9aec-fed471exxxx/$metadata#directoryObjects",
    "value": [
        {
            "odata.type": "Microsoft.DirectoryServices.Group",
            "objectId": "b5685a42-1de7-478d-94b4-de50ac9axxxx"
        }
    ]
}    Now I want to get only b5685a42-1de7-478d-94b4-de50ac9axxxx

Comment: @KevinPham I don't think we can get the value directly. We need to parse the json result from the api and then we can get the value of obejctId.